# can not connect to mongodb locally: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

Tags: mongodb, web-development-server

i am trying to test connectivity to my local mongodb through mongo compass, but i still reach out same error, however the service was running properly before.
[click here to see connection outout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypjM9.png)

also, this is the most recent logs for mongodb:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-28T15:31:25.696+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4712102, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"Host failed in replica set","attr":{"replicaSet":"rs","host":"52.x.x.x:1996","error":{"code":202,"codeName":"NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit","errmsg":"Couldn't get a connection within the time limit of 500ms"},"action":{"dropConnections":false,"requestImmediateCheck":false,"outcome":{"host":":1996","success":false}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-28T15:31:36.195+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4333222, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM received failed isMaster","attr":{"host":"52.x.x.x:1996","error":"NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit of 500ms","replicaSet":"rs","isMasterReply":"{}"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-28T15:31:36.196+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4712102, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"Host failed in replica set","attr":{"replicaSet":"rs","host":"52.x.x.x:1996","error":{"code":202,"codeName":"NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit","errmsg":"Couldn't get a connection within the time limit of 500ms"},"action":{"dropConnections":false,"requestImmediateCheck":false,"outcome":{"host":":1996","success":false}}}}
```

i do not use atlas clustering, i just enabled replicaset in config file but till now i did not use it anymore.

Comment: it doesn't look like an local host MONGODB_URI 
Are you sure it is local ?

Comment: actually am testing local connectivity to my mongodb, but the server running mongo should be accessible from our application which running in another aws ec2 machine that's why i have used the connection string usually used in code.
but the problem is, i still could not access db from localhost using the mongo-compass

Comment: Most probably you should add id of your local machine in setting of atlas

Comment: @oussamaSeffai
i do not use atlas cluster, i just use mongod standard with replicaset enabled